# Remove numeral character from commandLink tag (JSF)

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying a bit of a Java Server Pages (JSP) framework called Java Server Faces (JSF). I made a base template and other client templates. The page is very simple, but there is a little problem that I can't solve:

To my left I have a div, which contains a form with the icon (or "logo") of the page and below the links. It turns out that when I get the link text for my Bean (or even if I write it directly in value), at the end of the string (commandLink) I get a "(#)".

[image]

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="blueprint/screen.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="blueprint/print.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>      
    <title><h:outputText value="Pagina principal de la prueba!"></h:outputText></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="esqueleto">
    <div id="top" class="span-24 Last">
        <h:outputText value="Dan Java Server Faces Test"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span-24 Last">
        <div id="left" class="span-8">
            <h:form>
                <div id="mLogo"><h:graphicImage library="images" name="Evil-Smile.png"/></div>
                <div id="item"><h:commandLink value="Primera pagina" action="#{pageControler.Primera()}"/></div>
            </h:form>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="span-16 Last">
            <div id="contenido">
            <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" class="span-24 Last">
        Bottom
    </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I thought they were CSS themes from the text-decoration, and as you can see, I have placed it as "none". How do I get rid of this annoying "(#)"?